# pass a variable value as an input to an oracle sql file that is being called from a shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, variable, input, sql

Wanted to know if it is possible to "pass a variable value as an input to an oracle sql file that is being called from a shell script"

I am trying like this, but its not working:

SQL file:

```
set head on
set feed on
set termout off
set trimspool on

spool ts_verify.log
select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name='$ts_name';
spool off

set termout on
set trimspool off
exit
```

Shell script:

```
ts_name=''
echo "Please enter the Tablespace Name for which you want to add datafile"
read ts_name

sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << EOF

@ts.sql

EXIT
EOF
```

Regards,
Aditya

Comment: You are wide open to sql injection: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your SQL script into a template file with placeholders that are *really* easy to match.  Then create the real SQL script from the template when you know the values of the variables:

`template.sql`:

```
set head on
set feed on
set termout off
set trimspool on

spool ts_verify.log
select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name='@@TABLESPACENAME@@';
spool off

set termout on
set trimspool off
exit
```

Your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset ts_name
echo "Please enter the Tablespace Name for which you want to add datafile"
read -r ts_name

# create real SQL script and pass it to `sqlplus`:
sed "s/@@TABLESPACENAME@@/$ts_name/g" template.sql |
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba"
```

Comment: @ Mr. Kusalananda. It worked perfectly. Thank you for the help.